# kubectl_manifest yaml_body keeps changing

Tags: terraform, kubectl

kubectl_manifest keeps changing the yaml_body when applying terraform apply.

For this use case, I can not use kubernetes_manifest.
Do you have any comments on the cause and suggestions for resolving this issue?

```
  # module.mymodule.kubectl_manifest.someresource will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "kubectl_manifest" "someresource " {
        id                      = ""
        name                    = ""
      ~ yaml_body               = (sensitive value)
        # (14 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 33 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Terraform v1.3.1

```
    kubectl = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = ">= 1.14.0"
    }
```

Comment: Wait, your output shows you are using the `kubernetes_manifest` resource but then you say `I can not use kubernetes_manifest`. Which one is true?

Comment: My output shows that I am using kubectl_manifest; where do you see kubernetes_manifest?

Comment: Ok, so this is not an official provider. Additionally, depending on the type of cluster you are using, it could be that the YAML content is changing because the credentials to connect to a K8s cluster are short-lived. I would expect that to be true for example for any managed cluster, like EKS.

Comment: My terraform code runs on AKS

Comment: Well, yes, so I guess the credentials, i.e., YAML is refreshed from time to time.

Comment: Do you what kind of fields change exactly?
Considering to use ignore_fields = ["webhooks.0.clientConfig.caBundle"]

Comment: I don't know exactly, but usually some kind of a token or something similar is changed. Also not sure ignoring would help anything, I would expect if the credentials are changed you wouldn't be able to perform any actions on the cluster.